# Jersey, osgi and Servlet context 3.x

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, osgi

I am developing an application with Jersey 2.x and OSGI.
To register the end point of jersey (ServletContainer), I use the HTTPService of osgi with an implementation of Jetty 8.x
I want to use SSE (Server Sent Event), but unfortunately when I use the service that implements it, tells me that ***this does not run in a Servlet Context 2.x***
The strange is that the stack I use is servlet 3.x.
If I make a simple servlet with SSE support goes well regardless of JAX-RS.
I think that Jersey starts thinking that runs on a servlet container 2.x, but not how to change that.
I do not have any web.xml because it is a native application OSGI.

This is the simple initialization with OSGI:

```
httpService.registerServlet ("/ kratos / rest" (HttpServlet) ServletContext, null, null);
```

where servletContext is an instance of ServletContainer.

Then the ServletContainer instance, we add JAX services dynamically reloading the application.

Any suggestions?

Thanks ....

EDIT ...

These are some of the bundles:

```
karaf@root> la  | grep Se
[   3] [Active     ] [            ] [    8] OPS4J Pax Logging - Service (1.7.1)
[   5] [Active     ] [            ] [   10] Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.6.0)
[  10] [Active     ] [            ] [   20] Apache Aries Proxy Service (1.0.1)
[  49] [Active     ] [Created     ] [   30] Apache Karaf :: Management :: MBeans :: Services (2.3.3)
[  54] [Active     ] [            ] [   30] Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Activation API 1.4 (1.9.0)
[  55] [Active     ] [            ] [   30] Servlet 3.0 (1.0)
[  60] [Active     ] [            ] [   30] Jetty :: Aggregate :: All Server (8.1.9.v20130131)
[  67] [Active     ] [            ] [   30] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: asm (3.3.0.2)
[  69] [Active     ] [            ] [   30] OPS4J Pax Web - Service SPI (3.0.2)
[ 105] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: javax.inject (1.0.0.1)
[ 112] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] ServiceLocator Default Implementation (2.2.0.b10)
[ 121] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: aopalliance (1.0.0.5)
```

This is a Exception:

```
013-11-03 20:50:27,708 | WARN  | qtp18651544-59   | ServletHandler                   | pse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  492 | 60 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.9.v20130131 | 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.                                                                                         
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.                                                                                                              
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        ... 29 more
2013-11-03 20:50:27,710 | WARN  | qtp18651544-59   | ServletHandler                   | pse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  517 | 60 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.9.v20130131 | /kratos/rest/sse
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$1.suspend(WebComponent.java:120)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.suspend(ResponseWriter.java:109)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:621)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:357)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:347)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:258)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)[149:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-common:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:235)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)[150:org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-server:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:359)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)[147:org.glassfish.jersey.containers.jersey-container-servlet-core:2.3.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[71:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.0.2]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:210)[71:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.0.2]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:77)[71:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.0.2]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[60:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.9.v20130131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_40]
```

Example:

Note: I use Peaberry for DI.

Activator.java

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

   ....
   ....

   @Override
   public void start(final BundleContext bc) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Starting Activator");

        final ClassLoader primaryClassLoader = getDatanucleusClassLoader(bc);

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(Peaberry.osgiModule(bc), new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {

                install(new CoreResourcesJaxRsModule());
                ...
                ...
                 bind(HttpService.class).toProvider(Peaberry.service(HttpService.class).single());

                ...
             }
        });
   }
}
```

ConfigHttpService.java:

Singleton
public class ConfigHttpService {

```
private final ServletContainer servletContext;
private final HttpService httpService;
private final BundleContext context;
private boolean initialized = false;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConfigHttpService.class.getName());

@Inject
public ConfigHttpService(
        BundleContext bc,
        HttpService httpService, 
        ServletContainer context) {
    this.servletContext = context;
    this.httpService = httpService;
    this.context = bc;
}

public synchronized void init() throws Exception {
    if (!initialized) {
        try {
            logger.info("Configurado el registro de Guice");
            //httpService.registerFilter( guiceFilter, "/.*", null, 0, null );
            try {

                logger.info("Configurado el registro de recursos estaticos");
                httpService.registerResources("/kratos/pages", "/pages", null);

                 logger.info("Servlet /kratos/events configurado");
                 Dictionary d1 = new Hashtable();
                 d1.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.workingflows.kratos.core.service.KratosServiceApplication");

                 httpService.registerServlet("/kratos/rest", (HttpServlet) servletContext, d1, null);




                //httpService.registerResources("/kratos", "/js", null);
            } catch (NamespaceException ex) {
                logger.info("Error NamespaceException");
            }
        } catch (ServletException ex) {
            logger.info("Error ServletException");
        }
        initialized = true;
    }

}

@Stop
public void stop() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Eliminando el servlet {0}", "/kratos/rest");
    httpService.unregister("/kratos/rest");
    httpService.unregisterFilter(guiceFilter);
}
```

}

The method ConfigHttpService.init() is called from other class that represents a internal module. In this method, you will see the confguration of JAX ServletContext.

Comment: What makes you think that you are running in a Servlet 3.0 stack?

Comment: The project dependencies are servlet 3.x. Also I have a servlet asynchronous, it works fine. But JAX acts as if it were running on 2.x

Comment: I edit the original post, where will see the exception and some dependencies.

Comment: Project dependencies probably means build dependencies, right? But they are irrelevant, because the error happens at runtime, not build time.

Comment: as it is running with Pax-Web 3.0.2, Servlet 3.0 is available. Might want to ask a question at the ops4j mailing list and maybe provide a sample.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck I'm not convinced this is a Servlet 3.0 implementation. The question states he is using OSGi HttpService, which supports only Servlet 2.1.

Comment: @NeilBartlett, as I'm the maintainer for Pax-Web and therefore added the Servlet 3.0 support, I know Servlet 3.0 is available ;-)

Comment: @AchimNierbeck I don't doubt your knowledge of Pax Web! But notice there is a "Jetty Aggregate All Server" bundle present. Is it possible the OP's application is completely ignoring Pax Web and using an HttpService implementation from that bundle instead?

Comment: @NeilBartlett, only Pax-Web does register the HttpService, and it's using the "Jetty Aggregate All" bundle. See also https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/pax-web-3.0.x/pax-web-features/src/main/resources/features.xml. So it's rather unlikely unless he did mess something up ;)

Comment: @CristianRinaldi, anyway if you could provide me with a sample I might be able to look into this, and check what might be the issue ...

Comment: @AchimNierbeck Okay thanks for confirming. Sorry for doubting you. I have just seen way too many problems where the user wasn't even using the component he thought he was using!

Comment: @AchimNierbeck I Edit the post with an example.

Comment: @NeilBartlett, that's why we always say to use Karaf, it helps to ship around those tricky parts ;)

Comment: @AchimNierbeck "always use Karaf"... crikey, no!! We didn't build the world's best modular framework (OSGi) only for people to turn it back into a monolithic App Server. But I suspect we will have to agree to disagree here.

Comment: @NeilBartlett, :) we certainly agree on the modular framework but I guess we need to discuss that monolithic App Server thing once over a beer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was that the jersey modules were initiated on the same level as the module of the application that registered the ServletContainer class.

```
[ 127] [  Resolved] [   30] jersey-container-servlet-core (2.4.0)
[ 161] [    Active] [   30] jersey-core-common (2.4.0)
[ 162] [    Active] [   30] jersey-core-client (2.4.0)
[ 163] [    Active] [   30] jersey-core-server (2.4.0)
[ 164] [    Active] [   30] jersey-container-servlet (2.4.0)
[ 165] [    Active] [   30] jersey-media-sse (2.4.0)
```

I start the stack of jersey in level 30, and the application at level 80 and everything works!!!! The important module is jersey-core-server, that adds support for servlet 3.x.

```
[ 168] [    Active] [   80] OsgiJersey OSGi Bundle (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

See example in [my repository](https://github.com/csrinaldi/powercode)

Answer (score 1):

I think we might have a better solution for this, instead of using the HttpService directly you either can use the WhiteBoard extender (just need to install the http-whiteboard feature for this). This way you register a Servlet as a service and the whiteboard extender will pick this up, see also one of the [pax-web samples](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/whiteboard/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/extender/samples/whiteboard/internal/Activator.java). Or as you're developing a Servlet 3.0 Servlet just register it by annotating the Servlet. All you need to do is to add a web-contextPath to the Manifest of the Bundle. See also my [blog](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2013/02/just-annotation/) about this.

If this still doesn't help I could need a working sample sent to the ops4j mailinglist, or add a issue to pax-web so I can take a deeper look at it. BTW. CXF does use the whiteboard approach and works like a charm ;)

Comment: I changed the code, and I using WebContainer for registering a servlet (ServletContainer of Jersey). But the error is a NOT FOUND!!! in the browser when try access a jax resource. If I change webContainer to httpService, the resource is accessed without error. But, with httpService, the error is when I use SSE, as explained in the post.

Comment: As I never used Jersey before it really would be great if you could provide a small sample so I can try myself, please provide at the ops4j mailinglist otherwise I'm not able to help any further ...

Comment: @AchumNierbeck I'll make a small example and I will upload. I found a difference in the way of recording routes between HTTPService and WebContainer classes. 

`1) httpservice.registrerServlet("/rest/", ......)
2) webcontainer.registrerServlet( servlet, "Name", new String[]{"/rest/*"} ...)`

1) Only "/rest" 
2) If not add /* not found any resources. 

But the problem, I think is Jersey, this not discover that run in servlet 3.x container. Any other servlet run perfectly with WebContainer class. 

I will upload a sample with the code. 

Thanks.

Comment: that's why I need a sample to debug into, and check if Pax-Web needs to "provide" something to tell the version of Servlet :-)

Comment: @AchumNierbeck This is a [link](https://github.com/csrinaldi/powercode.git) to an example in my repository (OsgiJersey). I using pax-web 3.0.2 and jersey 2.3.1. The example register a static resource that call a sse resource. In the log of karaf you will see the error related to the servlet container.